# Android: best way to show data

Tags: android, performance

I need an advice to the best way retrieve and show some data.

I have a service which compute and saves data from GPS (every 500ms) and JSON (every 30 sec) inside a sqlite localdb.

The data is stored in two tables: header (updated every time) and detail (add new row every time).

What I want to do now, is use this data (it is about 20-25 variables) saved in header table and bind it to an activity and some fragments.

The main activity is composed by a main fragment and a 
FragmentStatePagerAdapter (with at least 3 fragments loaded inside)

Which is the best way to show this data?

I thought to:
- Create a "Bundle" and use handler and messages (Service -> Activity, Activity -> Fragments).
- Create a "Bundle" and use a local broadcast to send and receive data in every fragments loaded.
- Use a LoaderCallbacks and SimpleCursorAdapter with "FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER" in every fragment and retreive and show data directly from database.

What do you think is the best one? 
(In terms of performance, best practices and low memory consuption)

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of

> Use a LoaderCallbacks and SimpleCursorAdapter with
>   "FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER" in every fragment and retreive and
>   show data directly from database.

you will do unnecessary retrieving data from database, while you can simply receive it from broadcast.

I think the best way is to register broadcast receiver and take "ready for display" data from your service.

Comment: Do you think that Broadcast Receiver is faster than load data directly from db?

Comment: yes, because to fetch data from db, you need to some async stuff, but in case of broadcast receiver you don't need such things, you just get your data and display it